# C#: Dbreader values not updating on loop

Tags: c#

I am reading through a sql database, but my dbreader values doesnt update. Is there any way I can clear the values and get the new values as it loops through?

```
for (int i = 0; i < schdlrefno.Count; i++)
{
  reschdl = schdlrefno[i];                    
  reSQL = " SELECT schdl, techid, appdatetime, section  FROM dbo.name WHERE schdl_refno ='" + reschdl + "' ";

  OdbcCommand DbCommand = conn.CreateCommand();
  DbCommand.CommandText = reSQL;
  DbCommand.CommandTimeout = 180;

  OdbcDataReader DbReader = DbCommand.ExecuteReader();

  if (DbReader.Read())
  {
    APPDT = "";
    SCHEDULEREFNO = DbReader.GetString(DbReader.GetOrdinal("schdl"));
    TECHID = DbReader.GetString(DbReader.GetOrdinal("techid"));
    APPDT = DbReader.GetString(DbReader.GetOrdinal("appdatetime"));
    SECTIONNAME = DbReader.GetString(DbReader.GetOrdinal("section"));
   }
   OdbcConnection reconn;
                                   
   console.Writeline(APPDT);
}
```

Comment: Yikes. This looks scary-vulnerable to sql injection issues.

Comment: Why do you need loop here?

Comment: Is the FROM and WHERE keywords optional now?

Comment: Also, four other big issues. First, the SQL is invalid. There's no FROM or WHERE, which _is_ legal, but you need some context for the `=` comparison and column names. Second, this appends to `reSQL` on each iteration, so by the end of the loop you're running a LOT of statements with the one command. Third, `DbCommand` conflicts with a type name that's likely in scope here. Most people just use `command` or `cmd`. Finally, the loop assigns to the same variables on each iteration, meaning they'll just be overwritten with the last statement.

Comment: Even if the loop works, your variables will only hold the last record.

Comment: so sorry guys, I've added the FROM and WHERE. I have a loop of ticket references[schdl_refno], and I want to loop through each of them, connect to the database and get new values each time. It goes through and gets the values the first loop, but doesnt update after

Comment: `reSQL +=` should be `reSQL =`, but not using parameters is also a huge problem, as mentioned already.

Comment: Can you be more specific about "doesn't update after"? Doesn't update the database? The screen? The array?

Comment: it doesnt update the variables SCHEDULEREFNO, TECHID, APPDT, SECTIONNAME. So on the first iteration, the variables get their corresponding values but it should update in the second iteration with the new values but still keeps a record of the old one.

Comment: This is likely because of the `+=` operator. Each iteration of the loop first runs the queries from all the previous iterations. When assigning to those variables, it's looking at values from the first result set, rather than the new/current result set. With my answer, this part is fixed... it will write current data into those variables... but since those are single variables rather than collection, it's also overwriting prior iterations. At the end of the code, only the **last** values will show.

Answer (score 1):

There are still problems here, but it fixes four of the five issues from my two comments above, and demonstrates a much better way to structure the code:

```cs
string reSQL = "SELECT schdl, techid, appdatetime, section FROM dbo.name WHERE schdl_refno = @reschdl";
// Do NOT try to re-use the same connection object throughout your app!
using (var conn = new OdbcConnection("connection string here"))
using (var cmd = new OdbcCommand(reSQL, conn))
{
    //Make sure the type and length here match the column. This info isn't in the question, so I had to guess.
    var p = cmd.Parameters.Add("@reschdl", OdbcType.VarChar, 80);
    conn.Open()

    foreach(var reschdl in schdlrefno)
    {
        p.Value = reschdl;
        var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if (reader.Read())
        {
            //We're still overwriting these on each iteration!
            APPDT = "";
            SCHEDULEREFNO = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("schdl"));
            TECHID = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("techid"));
            APPDT = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("appdatetime"));
            SECTIONNAME = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("section"));
        }
        Console.Writeline(APPDT);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Joel, I appreciate it. especially for the right code to use. Will give that a go